# Error while insert rendering Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have created a placeholder **careers-main** and allowed a number of renderings in it. When I opened the page editor it added some of renderings but not all. The renderings which are not getting added I checked the browser console and found some errors. I am not sure why this is so?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the entire console log? Looks like your error maybe due to malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having check on my view for null check of current item and template id. There was not HTML outside the null check. So when I tried to add rendering in Page Editor, current item was null. so no html was returned(empty  view was returned). This break the Chrome Browser's Javascript and hence I was not able to add Rendering.

so solution is to return some html tag (may be empty)

```
<span> @if(currentItem!=null) { <h1>currentItem["Title"]</h1> } </span>
```